# Show that$ f(U)$ is open in $R^n$

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f : {R}^n → {R}^n$ is a continuously differentiable function such that $f '(x)$ is injective for every $x \in {R}^n$. Show that $f(U)$ is open in ${R}^n$, for every open set $U \subset {R}^n$.

So I'm trying to work off this question I found ([Let $g:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and injective. Show that $g(U)$ is open if $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ open.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487822/let-g-mathbb-rn-rightarrow-mathbb-r-continuous-and-injective-show-that-g?rq=1)) and I was wondering if that would work or is there a better more clean way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x^*\in U$ and let $y^*=f(x^*)$. We are given that $f'(x^*)$ is invertible and so the inverse function theorem gives us open sets $V,W$ such that $x^* \in V, y^* \in W$, $W=f(V)$ and a $C^1$ function $h:W \to V$ such that $h(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in V$.

Let $O \subset U \cap V$ be open and $x^* \in O$ and $P = f(O)$. Since $f(O) = h^{-1}(O)$ and $h$ is continuous ($C^1$ in fact) we see that $P$ is open and hence $y^* \in P \subset f(U)$ and so $f(U)$ is open.